# Error "Unit mariadb.service not found" after installing mariadb-server

Tags: linux, fedora, lamp

So I installed Mysql8.0 first, then i saw a post about it confliting with mariadb so I unninstalled mysql (**`dnf remove mysql-community-server`**) after that i installed mariadb-server(**`dnf install mariadb-server`**).

After I used "**`nano /etc/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf`**" and typed:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
```

Then I used **`systemctl start mariadb`** and it gave me this error:
**"Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit mariadb.service not found"**

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). You will get many more useful answers (and fewer downvotes) if you post this question to an appropriate site.

Comment: That said, you need to initialize the db structure before it will start, see [MariaDB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/MariaDB)